# Asp MVC best practice: use ajax or Ajax Helper?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP MVC is possible to make a post using the Ajax Helper

```
Ajax.BeginForm(...)
```

or using the standard

```
 $.ajax({
          url: "../TmpUrl,
          type: 'POST',
          ....
```

It's the best practice (style, performance reason and readness of code) to use the Ajax Helper offered by the Microsoft or using the standar ajax?

Comment: In asp.net 5 ajax helpers are removed, so i would suggest using ajax in new projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all depends on how you want to organize your code. If you depend too much on helpers, and also have other html helpers for tags/components (some UI frameworks come with MVC helper support). If that's your case, go ahead and use the helper syntax.

On the other hand, usually it's good practice to keep your scripts in another file, preferably an application.js file which you can access from all your views. In this scenario you might re-use some functions and reduce the number of lines in your code. But that cannot happen if you use helpers becase helper support is only in views.

One other downside of helper usage for ajax is that, the Ajax Helper (and all the helper syntax) may be due to change when MVC comes with a new version. That means you might need to refactor your views when that happens.

ltdr; I'd reccomend the standard js syntax, and on top of that I'd suggest you to put your scripts in an external js file, organize the functions and ajax calls in that file.